# RuntimeError: SSH to the cluster failed to start when using telepresence

Tags: kubernetes, telepresence

When I am using telepresence to debug remote kubernetes,throw this error:

```
RuntimeError: SSH to the cluster failed to start
```

This is the detail output:

```
~ ⌚ 17:26:43
$ telepresence
T: How Telepresence uses sudo: https://www.telepresence.io/reference/install#dependencies
T: Invoking sudo. Please enter your sudo password.
Password:
T: Starting proxy with method 'vpn-tcp', which has the following limitations: All processes are affected, only one telepresence can run
T: per machine, and you can't use other VPNs. You may need to add cloud hosts and headless services with --also-proxy. For a full list
T: of method limitations see https://telepresence.io/reference/methods.html
T: Volumes are rooted at $TELEPRESENCE_ROOT. See https://telepresence.io/howto/volumes.html for details.
T: Starting network proxy to cluster using new Deployment telepresence-1582277212-643104-29913

Looks like there's a bug in our code. Sorry about that!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/telepresence/telepresence/cli.py", line 135, in crash_reporting
    yield
  File "/usr/local/bin/telepresence/telepresence/main.py", line 68, in main
    socks_port, ssh = do_connect(runner, remote_info)
  File "/usr/local/bin/telepresence/telepresence/connect/connect.py", line 119, in do_connect
    args.from_pod
  File "/usr/local/bin/telepresence/telepresence/connect/connect.py", line 70, in connect
    raise RuntimeError("SSH to the cluster failed to start. See logfile.")
RuntimeError: SSH to the cluster failed to start. See logfile.


Here are the last few lines of the logfile (see /Users/dolphin/telepresence.log for the complete logs):

  50.2  37 | QoS Class:       Burstable
  50.2  37 | Node-Selectors:  <none>
  50.2  37 | Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 360s
  50.2  37 |                  node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 360s
  50.2  37 | Events:
  50.2  37 |   Type    Reason     Age   From                    Message
  50.2  37 |   ----    ------     ----  ----                    -------
  50.2  37 |   Normal  Scheduled  38s   default-scheduler       Successfully assigned dabai-fat/telepresence-1582277212-643104-29913-7bb5765b6-7xflh to azshara-k8s01
  50.2  37 |   Normal  Pulled     35s   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Container image "datawire/telepresence-k8s:0.104" already present on machine
  50.2  37 |   Normal  Created    34s   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Created container telepresence-1582277212-643104-29913
  50.2  37 |   Normal  Started    34s   kubelet, azshara-k8s01  Started container telepresence-1582277212-643104-29913
  50.2 TEL | [37] ran in 0.50 secs.
```

what should I do to fix this problem? My kubernetes server version is 1.15.2.Client version:1.17.3.

Comment: As it tells you, look in the log for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install socat in your remote kuberentes cluster host,I am using CentOS,so install like this:

```
sudo yum install socat -y
```

If using ubuntu/debian,install like this:

```
sudo apt-get install socat -y
```